# Linked List, copy list to another list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to copy a list into another list.

I have this:

```
template< typename T > class List {
    class Node {
    public:
        T element;
        Node *next;

        Node( T a_element, Node * a_suivant = nullptr );
        virtual ~Node( void );
    };

    int _taille;
    Node * _first;
    Node * _last;

    public:
    List( void );
    virtual ~List( void );

    int taille( void );
    bool empty( void );
```

I'm trying to create a function that copies a list (using this) into another list and empty the list in argument. I tried to start with emptying the list first to see if it works but I always get segmentation error.

```
void copyEmpty( List< T > & a_List ){
    Node *c = a_List._last;
    while(c!=NULL){
      Node *t = c->next;
      delete c; 
      c = t;
      if(c==a_List._last) c = NULL;
    }
    a_List._last = NULL;
}
```

How can I implement the function using `next`, `_last`, `_first` of the list in use (`this`) and the list in argument (`a_List`)?

Comment: Related, if this is supposed to do as you say  (e.g. copy nodes, then empty the source list, wouldn't a proper name be `moveFrom` (and in so being, hint at a much simpler approach than copying nodes) ? Second (and related), nowhere in your `copyEmpty` to you ever reference *anything* having to do with members of the active object (this). That alone should be a hint something is way off.

Comment: Perhaps one of the [Copy constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) or [Move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) is what you are looking for.

Comment: not constructors, I need a method or a function, i'm going to implement it in a template afterwards

Comment: Why do you start with ` Node *c = a_List._last;` the last node? Don't you want to start with _first?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but `"I'm trying to create a function that copies a list (using this) into another list and empty the list in argument."` -- isn't that exactly what a [Move Constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) is for? A template implementation is fine.

Comment: yes but I wanted to start with emptying the list in argument first to see if I have control over the nodes, I'm still new in c++ and this is my first project in linked lists

Comment: The best way to understand linked lists is to draw pictures. Step-by-step draw what you want to happen to copy two nodes from list A to list B. Then Step-by-step follow your coded instructions and compare the two sets of drawings. If they don't match, you have a problem. If the conceptual drawings are good, you'll be able to see exactly where the code deviates and start fixing.

Comment: @user4581301 Therefore, you need to buy an easel, preferably oil paints or watercolors, and go to nature. :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow all life that we know of eventually boils down to linked lists.

Comment: After thinking a bit about the create and delete approach -- none of that is needed. With your template class what you are doing is simply changing the class name (the list is the same -- you just call it by another name) For that standpoint, you can use a member function to create a new instance and invoke the copy constructor that simply sets the new `_first` and `_last` to the existing pointers and then sets `this->_first = nullptr;` deleting the old list and returns the new list.

Answer (score 0):

Above of all, it seems you are a C programmer...

- Don't use `( void )` in C++!
- Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`! (This might become important for overloaded functions taking pointers if you want to make use of `std::nullptr_t`, the null pointer type, which is defined as `decltype(nullptr)`)
- Use, like @david-c-rankin mentioned, a move constructor, or move operator = for your purpose to be compliant with standard design in C++. At least one of them will also work in your *template context* you mentioned in a comment.

Now coming to the problem: I don't claim that this is a solution since I'm not sure if a got your question right.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class List {
    class Node {
    public:
        T element;
        Node* next;

        Node( const T& a_element, Node* a_suivant = nullptr );
        virtual ~Node();
    };

    int _taille;
    Node* _first;
    Node* _last;

    public:
    List();
    virtual ~List();

    int taille();
    bool empty();
};

template <class T>
void copyEmpty( List< T > & a_List ){
    for(auto pNode = a_List._first; pNode != a_List._last;){
        Node* const pNext{ pNode->next };
        delete pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    delete a_List._last;
    a_List._last = nullptr;
    a_List._first = nullptr; 
}
```

For now I kept your function name. There is still the need of tackling the privateness of _last etc.

I think in your solution you skip deleting the last one.

Maybe you may add a clear specification what `_first`, `_last` and your function are / do respectively.

Comment: if `a_List._last` wasn't `delete`ed when iterating through the linked list, the list was broken before the function entered. Shouldn't be any need to `delete` it after the loop.

Comment: The end condition of the loop is such that the last element won't be treated. This is natural according to that you normally would compare against some past-the-end iterator, which is not the case here. @user4581301

Comment: @Necktschnagge Your answer does not make great sense because at least it is unclear whether the function is a member function of the class or not. Also why does the inner class Node has a virtual destructor?

Comment: I see. I missed that you used an unusual exit condition on the loop. Why not iterate until null?

Comment: @Necktschnagge Moreover the function definition has an error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I added a `template<...>` right before `void copyEmpty`. You are right in all your points. Well, I just copied from the question. The whole stuff does not make much sense to me either since there are plenty methods that are just declared in the question. I focused on the function `copyEmpty`.

Comment: @Necktschnagge There is one more error in the function definition.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't know what mistake you see. The signature is weird since `copyEmpty` is no class member and takes only one argument.

Comment: @Necktschnagge Variables pNode and pNext have different qualifiers. So this assignment  pNode = pNext; is incorrect.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ahh, I missplaced the `const`. Of course, you're right.

Comment: @user4581301 Good point to iterate until reachign `nullptr`. Actually, I don't know if the last pointer is guaranteed to be `nullptr`. There was no precise description in the question. _(Actually there are way more things left unclear)_